# angularjs $timeout in Angular14

Tags: angularjs, rxjs, timeout, angular14

Below code is for angularJs and I Want to achieve same functionality/behaviour in Angular 14

```
var getData = $timeout(function () {
     return $q(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (someCondition) {
          resolve('data received!');
        } else {
          reject('something went wrong!');
        }
      });
    }, 2000);
```

and cancel behavior

```
$timeout.cancel(getData)
```

I know there could be a JavaScript solution with `setTimeout`
but not sure if should I go with that or use RxJs maybe?

Comment: Better to use rxjs.

Comment: @AvgustinTomsic, how ? can you share a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

should be something like:

```
   const obs$ = of({}).pipe(delay(2000), concatMap(() => {
     if (someCOndition) {
        return of('data received!');
     } else {
        throw new Error('something went wrong!');
     }
   }));

   const subscription = obs$.subscribe(...);
   // if want to cancel
   subscription.unsubscribe();
```